# Intermediate value property supremum infimum

Tags: real-analysis

We know if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then it achieves its supremum $M$ and infimum $m$ and due to intermediate value property, it achieves any value in $[m,M]$. I am wondering what if $f$ is not continuous but only has the intermediate value property, does it achieve all values in $(m,M)$?

I think the answer is yes, but my exercise which used this argument as a step specifically assumes continuity. So I think the real answer is no?

Comment: To make your search easier: Functions with the intermediate value property are called [Darboux functions](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Darboux_property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and take $x_m,x_M$ such that $f(x_m) <  m +\epsilon $ and $f(x_M) > M - \epsilon$ where $M,m$ are the supremum and infimum of the image of $f$, respectively. Then, $f$ takes on all values $(m + \epsilon, M-\epsilon)$ if you assume the intermediate value property. Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ shows that $f$ takes on all values in $(m,M)$.

An interesting fact however is that if $f$ is monotonic or $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed for every singleton $y$, then $f$ is in fact continuous. I can provide proof of this if you'd like

Comment: I think so too! Maybe my excercise used continuity somewhere else.

Comment: @MarsPlastic the OP asked for a proof of that. But you pose an interesting question

Comment: I know, I just realized that I had misread the question, that's why I deleted my comment.

Comment: In general, function with intermediate value property doesn't need to achieve infimum and maximum right?

Comment: In general, no, this does not happen.

Comment: Just read that. Do you have a counter example? Feel free to post it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145439/).